# set color scale limits for plot of sf object

Tags: r, r-sf

I would like to plot multiple sf objects on the same color scale. In the raster package, there is a very convenient `zlim` argument where you can specify the color limits. But I can't figure out what the equivalent would be in sf::plot().

Here, I load a sf polygon and create an additional dummy variable to illustrate my question:

```
library(sf)
nc_sf <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc_sf$AREA2 <- nc_sf$AREA * 2

range(nc_sf$AREA)
range(nc_sf$AREA2)

plot(nc_sf["AREA"])
plot(nc_sf["AREA2"])
```

[image]
[image]

These plot with independent color scales.

I can do this with ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

fullrange <- range(c(nc_sf$AREA, nc_sf$AREA2))
fullrange

ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nc_sf, aes(fill = AREA), lwd = 0.5, color = 'black') + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = sf.colors(), limits = fullrange)
ggplot() + geom_sf(data = nc_sf, aes(fill = AREA2), lwd = 0.5, color = 'black') + scale_fill_gradientn(colours = sf.colors(), limits = fullrange)
```

[image]
[image]

But how can I do this with sf::plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom `breaks`:

```r
library(sf)
nc_sf <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

nc_sf$AREA2 <- nc_sf$AREA * 2
fullrange <- c(nc_sf$AREA, nc_sf$AREA2)
mybreaks <- seq(min(fullrange), max(fullrange), by = diff(range(fullrange))/10) 
plot(nc_sf["AREA"], breaks=mybreaks)
```

[image]

```r
plot(nc_sf["AREA2"], breaks=mybreaks)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>